# How to let different types of authenticated/verified users intent to different Activities?

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have 2 types of users. I have already coded email & password verification in both of them. And their profile data are already stored in Firebase database.

In my Launcher activity which is my Welcome_page it has an app logo with 2 buttons for signing up as different users.

Now when the user signs up and fills out the fields necessary they can submit it and a toast will appear saying to check their email for the verification link.

So when I check my email using the emulator and go back to my app I am redirected to my welcome page. So I did some coding in it to check if user is verified. If they are verified then it will intent to another Activity, if not then sign up buttons will disappear and Toast will appear saying "Processing verification".

**My problem** is how to let the userType1 intent to UserType1.class while userType2 will intent to UserType2.class

I tried coding it to test if the userType's ID is stored in a specific userType of node in the database using the addListenerForSingleValueEvent()

Code so far looks like this:

```
public class Welcome_Page extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnUserType1, btnUserType2;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRefUserType1 = database.getReference();
DatabaseReference myRefUserType2 = database.getReference();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome__page);

    btnUserType1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUpUserType1);
    btnUserType2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUpUserType2);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



   if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
       final String uId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
       myRefUserType1 = myRefUserType1.child("users").child("UserType1");
       myRefUserType2 = myRefUserType2.child("users").child("UserType2");

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()) {
            myRefUserType1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                       if(ds.child(uId).exists()){
                           Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome_Page.this, UserType1.class);
                           startActivity(intent);
                       }
                   }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            myRefUserType2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if (ds.child(uId).exists()) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome_Page.this, UserType2.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Processing verification...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        btnUserType1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnUserType2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mAuth.getCurrentUser().reload();
        //finish();
    }
    //mAuth.signOut(). 
        btnUserType1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(Welcome_Page.this, SignUpUserType1.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
        });



        btnUserType2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Welcome_Page.this, SignUpUserType2.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Database:

```
{
 users:
 {
   userType1:
   {
     userType1_ID:
     {
       name     :  blach
       email    :  blach@gmail.com
       pass     :  123456
       user_Id  :  STwjhdaskjdfsadfi
     }
   }
   userType2:
   {
     userType2_ID:
      {
        name     :  asdfgh
        email    :  asdfgh@gmail.com
        pass     :  789012
        user_Id  :  KDIWOfhjdshfkjdffi
      }
   }
 }
}
```

But when I run the app the screen flashes white then it closes right after. There is not even a message saying that "App has stopped". There isn't anything in Logcat indicating which line of code to fix. The emulator also opens up the phone settings somehow after my app stops.

Everything was working fine before I added the addListenerForSingleValueEvent() for the intent. Though the users would be redirected to the same intent class at that time.

Can someone please tell me how to let them intent properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have in your database 2 different sections, `userType1` and `userType2`. Your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
     |
     --- userType1
     |     |
     |     --- userId1@email,com
     |     |       |
     |     |       --- //details
     |     |
     |     --- userId2@email,com
     |             |
     |             --- //details
     |
     --- userType2
           |
           --- userId3@email,com
           |       |
           |       --- //details
           |
           --- userId4@email,com
                   |
                   --- //details
```

As you probably see, the unique identifier between users is the `email address`. At login time, verify the user in each section exists. For this attach a listerner and use the `exists()` method on the `DataSnapshot` object. If the user is of type `userType1` display a Toast and redirect him to an actvity, if is of type `userType2`, display another Toast and redirect him to another activity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: My database has a users node, and the users node has 2 subnodes for the usertype1, usertype2. So I should change my database structure and remove the users child? And just store the user's data in the usertype child?  The users user_Id in database in also unique right? Is it okay to use that?

Comment: I provided you a database structure which is a little bit simpler but you can also use yours. You can also use the uid but the main ideea is to verifiy first from which section the user belongs. According to that, you can redirect the user to the desired activity. That's it!